# construct AST from string with libclang

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang, jit, libclang

I generate some c++ codes, and store it in string, I want to construct an AST tree from the string using libclang. How to do it? I don't want to string into extra files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CXUnsavedFile](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structCXUnsavedFile.html) to pass in-memory buffer to libclang.

Answer (score 1):

you can try such as the next code:

```
std::unique_ptr<ASTUnit> AST(tooling::buildASTFromCode("int x=10;x++;"));
TranslationUnitDecl *DC = AST->getASTContext().getTranslationUnitDecl();
if (DC) {
    llvm::errs() << "---------dump begin----------\n";
    DC->dump();
    llvm::errs() << "---------dump end----------\n";
    visitor.TraverseDecl(DC);
}
```